# bokeh show zoomed-in plot from start

Tags: python, bokeh

Say I have data plotted for 50 years

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import TimeSeries
df = pd.util.testing.makeTimeDataFrame(12500)
p = TimeSeries(df, tools = 'xwheel_zoom,reset')
```

When I open the html file, it shows the whole data and then I can zoom in. Is there a way to specify that when I open the html file, it only shows say last year's data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the x_range as explained [in the docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#setting-ranges)

This will dictate the initial zoom. The rest of the data will still be plotted if you zoom out like in this modified example from the docs:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Range1d

output_file("title.html")

# create a new plot with a range set with a tuple
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, x_range=(0, 20))

# set a range using a Range1d
p.y_range = Range1d(0, 15)

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 25], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7, 50], size=10)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question asked about a daterange axis this might need more clarification. Perhaps this will work.

This will zoom in around June 12, 2018.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Range1d

output_file("title.html")

date_times = pd.date_range('2018-06-11', periods=4, freq='D')
# set min and max date times for plotting
x_min = date_times[0]
x_max = date_times[-1]

# create a new plot with a range set with a tuple
p = figure(plot_width=400, 
           plot_height=400, 
           y_axis_type="linear",
           x_axis_type="datetime", 
           x_range=(x_min, x_max))

# set a range using a Range1d
p.y_range = Range1d(0, 15)

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 25], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7, 50], size=10)

show(p)
```